# Php include not executed

Tags: php, php-include

I'm learning Php

And i made a main index.php page
And at some point it contains the line

```
<?php
include './BaseTemplate.php';
?>
```

BaseTemplate.php contains a lot of common plain html that is equal between all pages.
It looks like (but these are only a few lines) :

```
echo '<script src = "../assets/js/intention.js"></script>';
echo '<script src = "../assets/js/context.js"></script>';
echo '<head><body>';
echo '<table>';
```

But these echo commands dont get executed how should i resolve this ?

Comment: Maybe there are errors in your script(s). Php log may help a lot with resolving "strange" errors/bugs.

Comment: Could you show us your folder hierachy

Comment: Do you have `<?php ?>` tags around your code in the BaseTemplate.php file? Files that are included need those there.

Comment: wel i answered my own question, suddenly i realized what i did wrong see below, but i cannt aprove it for up to 2 days as by forum rules here

Answer (score 0):

When you are including any file into your page the code for that file will come into the page.
So if the included file and the page where you are including it are in not in same path will create a problem.

It seems that you are getting that only. So please make the path in BaseTemplate.php according to the index.php, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I was thinking that include would put all code in a page from an external php source file. That's not the case, include files are libraries with functions which can be called.

So to resolve it, I rewrote it the BaseTemplate.php like this

```
<?php
Function WritePageBase() {       // now i put it all inside a callable function

  echo '<script src = "../assets/js/intention.js"></script>';
  echo '<script src = "../assets/js/context.js"></script>';
  echo '<head><body>';
  echo '<table>';
  }
 ?>
```

Now my other pages can call it like

```
 <?php
  include './BaseTemplate.php';   // include the file with functions
  WritePageBase();                // call the function to echo all html code in page
  ?>
```

which reduces a lot of html code which now can be edited by a single file (and all other pages using it will change too).